# How to download express documentation

Tags: express, wget

How can i download full api reference to express so that i can understand and code on localhost while i am not connected to internet

```
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express
```

This site has all api references but i am unable to download . 
There are other tags too if you see  http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html
I tied command

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows  --no-parent  http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express
```

This doesn't work .

If someone can share where i can get easily downloadable study material for express it would be great too .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is all one page:

```
curl http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express > express-doc.html
```